# update column collation with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collation, utf8mb4

I have a `case-insensitive` collation column in my table.

```
col_name : hash_id, collation : utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I am getting results for `yA2JeGs` and `YA2JeGs` when I search for former only.

So I need to update the collation to ensure `case-sensitivity` for that column.

I tried changing the collation for that column creating a new `migration` file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('product_match_unmatches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('hash_id')->collate('utf8mb4_bin')->change();
    });
}
```

Also with `$table->string('hash_id')->collation('utf8mb4_bin')->change();`

Migration runs successfully but the collation remains the same.

How do I do that in laravel?

Answer (score 11):

You need to create new migration and make  column case sensitive using laravel schema builder with code mentioned below :

```
$table->string('columName')->collation('utf8_bin')->change();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations

Comment: The docs seem to mention changing the collation as `collation('utf8mb4_bin')` and not `collate`

Comment: `utf8_cs` -- not in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

I can only change the collation with a raw query, the Blueprint change() method did not do a thing for me, unless I changed the field type too.

This worked for me:

```php
public function up()
{
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE tableName MODIFY columnName VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the collation at query time

```php
Model::where(\DB::raw('hash_id COLLATE utf8mb4_bin'), 'yA2JeGs');
```

However you should probably change the collation of the table itself since it seems that a case insensitive collation is the wrong collation to have used on that field to begin with.

Note: MySQL does not have a `utf8mb4_general_cs` collation. However if you are using only ASCII hash codes then `utf8mb4_bin` should be good enough.

Comment: I tried changing the collation of the table column but is the same. updated my post. please check

Answer (score 1):

Direct Collation is not working in the blueprint need to add charset.

This worked for me :

```
$table->text('message')->charset('utf8mb4')->collation('utf8mb4_general_ci')->nullable()->change();
```